# Calling API for GoogleMap objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, google-maps

Can anyone guide me how we can use place auto complete in GoogleMap after all the steps completed for installing pod for GoogleMaps into the project?? I have no idea about this please somebody help me!!!

Comment: see this once it helps you https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete

Comment: sir can you help on the problem i have mentioned below?

Answer (score 1):

I hope u have integrated google pods successfully

Import google map class

```
@import GoogleMaps;
```

Add delegate

```
<GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate>
```

I have button in my screen to go for autocomplete screen.
On button IBAction write this code

```
GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
acController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and implement GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate

```
- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewControllerdidAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  // Do something with the selected place.

  NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
  NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
  NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);
}                           

- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewControllerdidFailAutocompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  // TODO: handle the error.
  NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
}

// User canceled the operation.
- (void)wasCancelled:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

// Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
- (void)didRequestAutocompletePredictions:(GMSAutocompleteViewController*)viewController {
      [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
 }

 - (void)didUpdateAutocompletePredictions:(GMSAutocompleteViewController*)viewController {
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
 }
```

Comment: mam when i use your code it shows duplicate declaration on method 'viewController'

Comment: and if i comment this method "viewControllerdidFailAutocompleteWithError" this error generates   " Places API warning: Unable to find and load 'GooglePlaces.bundle'. This may be a sign that you've forgotten to include a resources bundle in your 'Copy Bundle Resources' build phase. As this bundle contains important resources, you may encounter missing images, translations and other incorrect behaviour"

Comment: @pri - you missed the bundle or framework  (google) to integrate in your project  , check once , see this once also may be it helps you http://sweettutos.com/2015/09/30/how-to-use-the-google-places-autocomplete-api-with-google-maps-sdk-on-ios/

Comment: sir this link is mentioned in swift